# Data race with std::unordered_map, despite locking insertions with mutex

Tags: c++, concurrency, stl, containers, unordered-map

I have a C++11 program that does some computations and uses a `std::unordered_map` to cache results of those computations. The program uses multiple threads and they use a shared `unordered_map` to store and share the results of the computations.

Based on my reading of `unordered_map` and STL container specs, as well as [unordered_map thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685486/unordered-map-thread-safety), it seems that an `unordered_map`, shared by multiple threads, can handle one thread writing at a time, but many readers at a time.

Therefore, I'm using a `std::mutex` to wrap my `insert()` calls to the map, so that at most only one thread is inserting at a time.

However, my `find()` calls do not have a mutex as, from my reading, it seems that many threads should be able to read at once. However, I'm occasionally getting data races (as detected by TSAN), manifesting themselves in a SEGV. The data race clearly points to the `insert()` and `find()` calls that I mentioned above.

When I wrap the `find()` calls in a mutex, the problem goes away. However, I don't want to serialize the concurrent reads, as I'm trying to make this program as fast as possible. (FYI: I'm running using gcc 5.4.)

Why is this happening? Is my understanding of the concurrency guarantees of `std::unordered_map` incorrect?

Comment: It sounds like you need a `shared_mutex` since all write and read calls need synchronization since you have a writer.

Comment: The answer in the linked thread says it: "*A. Multiple threads reading at the same time,* **or** *B. One thread writing at the same time*". Note the **or**.

Comment: You've misinterpreted the spec; it allows multiple readers, but not multiple readers regardless of the single writer.  You need a Multiple Reader/Single Writer lock like the shared_mutex mentioned in NathanOliver's comment

Comment: Thanks, all. This all makes sense. Re: shared_mutex, that does sound like right solution. I tried it, however, and I'm having trouble with it. I am now trying to use the approach described by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915152/c11-multiple-read-and-one-write-thread-mutex and am compiling with -std=c++14. However, while it is able to find the <shared_mutex> header (again, I'm running with gcc 5.4), I get `error: ‘shared_mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type`. It seems like shared_mutex may not be available until c++17? Any quick pointers on how to get this working?

Comment: Standard thread safety rules apply to `std::unordered_map` as they do to most classes. Standard thread safety means that a thread may not access an object while another thread is, or might be, modifying it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need a `mutex` for your readers to keep the writers out, but you need a *shared* one. `C++14` has a [std::shared_timed_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) that you can use along with scoped locks [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [std::shared_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) like this:

```
using mutex_type = std::shared_timed_mutex;
using read_only_lock  = std::shared_lock<mutex_type>;
using updatable_lock = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

mutex_type mtx;
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> m;

// code to update map
{
    updatable_lock lock(mtx);

    m[1] = "one";
}

// code to read from map
{
    read_only_lock lock(mtx);

    std::cout << m[1] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with that approach.

first, `std::unordered_map` has two overloads of `find` - one which is `const`, and one which is not.
 I'd dare to say that I don't believe that that non-const version of `find` will mutate the map, but still for the compiler invoking non const method from a multiple threads is a data race and some compilers actually use undefined behavior for nasty optimizations. 
so first thing - you need to make sure that when multiple threads invoke `std::unordered_map::find` they do it with the const version. that can be achieved by referencing the map with a const reference and then invoking `find` from there.

second, you miss the the part that many thread may invoke const find on your map, but other threads can not invoke non const method on the object! I can definitely imagine many threads call `find` and some call `insert` on the same time, causing a data race. imagine that, for example, `insert` makes the map's internal buffer reallocate while some other thread iterates it to find the wanted pair.

a solution to that is to use C++14 `shared_mutex` which has an exclusive/shared locking mode. when thread call `find`, it locks the lock on shared mode, when a thread calls `insert` it locks it on exclusive lock.

if your compiler does not support `shared_mutex`, you can use platform specific synchronization objects, like `pthread_rwlock_t` on Linux and `SRWLock` on Windows.

another possibility is to use lock-free hashmap, like the one provided by Intel's thread-building blocks library, or `concurrent_map` on MSVC concurrency runtime. the implementation itself uses lock-free algorithms which makes sure access is always thread-safe and fast on the same time.